# Instantiate a parameterized java class without knowing which one

Tags: java, generics, factory

In Java 6, they introduced SPI (service provider interface). It helped to instantiate an object that implements a certain interface, without knowing its exact class, but it only did so for raw types.

However, with SPI, I cannot instantiate parameterized classes like `Class<A,B>` that implements `SomeInterface<A,B>`.

How do I do that if I don't want to use any dependency framework like Spring or CDI, in order to keep my library agnostic of those DI frameworks?

Seems like I painted myself into a corner.

Comment: Did you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451734/loading-generic-service-implementations-via-java-util-serviceloader)?

Comment: Remember at run time, generics are erased and only the raw classes exist.  So really generics are just syntactic sugar for the compiler.  If that's not your use case, generics might not be the right fit for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @vbezhenar, that looks like a possible solution!